# updatedb command does not seem to update slocate.db

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I'm searching files with locate it complains that

> locate: warning: database /var/lib/slocate/slocate.db' is more than 8 days old

However running updatedb (as root) does not seem to have any effect. slocate.db file is still old.

```
# ls -l /var/lib/slocate/slocate.db
-rw-r----- 1 root slocate 847909 2011-01-11 10:58 /var/lib/slocate/slocate.db
```

The system is Ubuntu 8.04.4, 2.6.32.22

Of cause I still can use find, but naturally locate is much faster.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Does `sudo updatedb` give any error messages?

Comment: No. It takes few seconds and finishes without any messages.

Comment: I just tried this: `updatedb --output=/var/lib/slocate/slocate.db` and it updated the file. However now locate crashes with `locate: fatal error: set_path_head: prev_code_str == NULL.`. I guess that means that updatedb and locate are for some reason not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your updatedb is not from slocate in the first place, but, for example, GNU findutils.

Comment: Looks like you are right: I have `/usr/bin/locate -> /etc/alternatives/locate` and `/etc/alternatives/locate -> /usr/bin/slocate`, also `/usr/bin/updatedb -> /etc/alternatives/updatedb` and `/etc/alternatives/updatedb -> /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils`. I found that instead of updatedb I can run `locate -u` which obviously is the same `locate` I use for searching. Now I only need to get rid of findutils.

Comment: Hooray for Ubuntu screwing up packaging again. (That is why, in certain other distros, {updatedb, locate} are in _a single_ package so as to update both update-alternatives links at the same time, or, if so chosen, conflict with other implementations completely.)

Answer (score 1):

Check your crontab, cron should be running updatedb every night. Output errors from this should get mailed to root. There is some mention in the Ubuntu manual, search for 'locate' half way down the page:
[ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles)

Is it possible that you have both BSD and GNU locate on your system? There is info about locate db formats at [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)

Comment: As @jørgensen pointed out I have slocate and GNU findutils.